# Does QVariant call a destructor on the contained class?

Tags: c++, qt, qvariant

If I put a class with a destructor in a QVariant, will the QVariant's destruction call the proper destructor of the non-POD class it contains?

Here's an example, where I'm putting a class into a QVariant owned by a QWidget:

```
QVariant variant = QVariant::fromValue(MyObject());
widget->setProperty("ui", variant);
```

My expectation is that the lifetime of the dynamic variable I care about (MyObject) will last until the QWidget is destroyed, and at that time, MyObject will be properly destructed with a call the it's destructor.
(i.e. `~QWidget() -> ~QVariant() -> ~MyObject()`)

Comment: `MyObject()` is a pointer, not c'tor? But then where's the c'tor? Confused. Did you try a qDebug() in the MyObject d'tor?

Comment: If you pass a value in, the instance will be destroyed with QVariant, if you don't want, pass a pointer.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld My question is whether it gets destroyed *properly*, by calling the destructor.